# Script will be reset when returning to the page

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have built a function in Javascript that allows to focus input fields (similar to the Google Account login). The script works like this:

There is a heading in the input field. As soon as you click on the object and write something in, the heading shrinks and appears above the field. If you remove the text completely and click out of the input field, the focus disappears.

In the script it looks like this:

```
const reg_inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".reg-input");

function addcl() {
  const parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;

  parent.classList.add("focus");
}

function remcl() {
  const parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;

  if (this.value == "") {
    parent.classList.remove("focus");
    return false;
  }
}

reg_inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("focus", addcl);
  input.addEventListener("blur", remcl);
  return true;
});
```

The problem is that the user is taken to another page when he clicks a button. If the user now returns to the old page, the heading is again in the input field and covers the normal, entered text. This looks very unfriendly and should be fixed. I think the script will be reset on return. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web pages are **stateless**.

This means if you run a script on a webpage and then leave the page and later return to it, the page will load as if the script has not yet run (because it hasn't).

There are however ways to report state to the browser:

- using the anchor `#` (eg. `example.com/my-page.html#my-state`)
- using a query string (eg. `example.com/my-page.html?state=my-state`)
- cookies
- using `webStorage` (either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`)

---

## More on `webStorage`

The `webStorage API` creates a simple key-value store which persists between page reloads *and* between different pages on the same site.

The difference between `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is that when you leave the website, any `sessionStorage` keys and values will be deleted.

If you like, the `webStorage API` can be thought of as (not quite, but) a bit like *"client-side cookies"*.

It's relatively painless to use.

About the only thing you need to remember is that each `webStorage` entry must be a `string` (not a `number`, an `array` or an `object`).

Even that isn't much of an issue, because we can communicate arrays and objects using `JSON`.

---

To add a string value to `localStorage`, use:

```
localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myStringValue');
```

To retrieve that string value from `localStorage`, use:

```
let myValue = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
```

To check if a key exists in `localStorage`, use:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('myKey') !== null)
```

To remove a string value from `localStorage`, use:

```
localStorage.removeItem('myKey');
```

To remove *all* string values from `localStorage`, use:

```
localStorage.clear();
```